# Rather ugly guys or guys rather ugly

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives

Do I have to say

> Rather ugly guys came into the line

or

> Guys rather ugly came into the line?

First one sounds fine to me but the second one sounds off to my ear, but I am not really sure.

Comment: _Rather ugly_ is composed of an emphasizer (rather) modifying an adjective. Exactly like _very unpleasant_. So which would you prefer: _very unpleasant accomodations_, or _accomodations very unpleasant_?

Comment: Aren't both of them correct? I mean, I am not quite sure about the second one, but it seems acceptable, this "accomodations very unpleasant."

Comment: No; only the ones with the nouns at the end are correct. The only adjectives that can follow the noun they modify are multi-word constituents. _Rather ugly_ is not a constituent, but rather one word modifying another, which modifies the noun; those go before. Afterwards are things like _the man standing on the corner, the woman in the red gown, a boy eleven years old_ (but note _an eleven-year-old boy_, where hyphens make it one word. Modifiers of one word always precede the noun.

Comment: "A guy both ugly and gloomy"  Can you please explain me why this is correct then? "both ugly and gloomy" comes after the "guy".

Comment: _Both ugly and gloomy_ is a constituent. _Rather ugly and  awkward_ is a constituent. But _rather ugly_ is just a an intensified adjective.

Comment: Is _not ugly and gloomy_ constituent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, modifying adjectives in English precede the noun they modify so "Rather ugly guys" describes the people joining your queue.

Comment: But there was this "rather", and when it is used with both, it becomes something like this: A guy both ugly and gloomy. Why is that?

Comment: "A guy both ugly and gloomy" uses a so-called reduced relative clause which parses as "A guy [who is} both ugly and gloomy."  The thing that "sounds off to" your ear (and will to your readers) is the echo of alternative parsing.  "Guys both" will make your reader consider (and have to discard) templates like "The guys both went to the mall."  "Guy both" will make your reader temporarily wonder why one guy is part of a sentence about a duo.